# How to chose priority for threads?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, kernel

Considering one core , when multiple request is arrived at server at the same timestamp, and all have the same priority ,for which request the thread would be allotted first ?

Ex: CPU has single core and has 2 thread. Now the 4 people has made the request (process) A,B,C,D to any server & server need to assign threads in the message queue in order to process those request. But which 2 process would be given chance first to assign those 2 threads ?

Assumption they all have arrived at same timestamp and have equal priority.

Comment: What you describe is not really possible. There is ultimately only one accept queue for the listening socket, and therefore no such thing as simultaneous requests. But in general it s random or round-robin among threads with equal priorities.

Comment: The question seems about programming in **user space** (unprivileged mode of the processor). Why do you use "kernel" tag which is for questions about OS **kernel** (privileged mode of the processor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TUSHAR, there is a bit of a language gap occurring here.  Considering you chose, *kernel*, and didn't seem to think it was something to do with algebra, I am going to translate your question:

> In a single CPU system, when multiple interrupts are asserted
> simultaneously, and all have the same priority, which handler would be
> serviced first?

The first bit of info is that most interrupt controllers are little more than a *priority encoder* with some extra glue.  As such, they have no notion of *same priority*, but that is less important than you might think.

Real Time Operating Systems, in particular, seek to disassociate their implementation with the hardware, and may even dynamically adjust interrupt priorities to suit the current workload.  The key here is that the OS spends a minimal time at the mercy of the interrupt controller, and chooses what to do based upon its state.  As the system designer, you can choose what happens.

Time Sharing Operating Systems also have some control over this; but typically less as they strive for maximum throughput rather than predictable response.  As such, they might do anything from first-in-first-served, random-served, or even random-starved.

So the answer to your question depends upon your environment.   For the most part, if you have a very simple environment (eg. an executive like vxWorks or freeRTOS), expect it to follow the dictates of the interrupt controller.   If you have a more sophisticated device OS (eg. INTEGRITY or QNX) it is up to your configuration.   If you have Linux/winDOS, there are likely 320 control knobs that all result in burning the toast.